# Non Primary receiver not receiving payments

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to test the Paypal Delayed Chained Payment API's.

There are two receivers 'A' and 'B', A is a primary receiver (US) and B is the second receiver (MX) when I release the payment using the Execute API the second receiver is not receiving the payment but the payments are being deducted from the buyer and primary accounts.

I am adding the request array below.

```
[
  'actionType' => 'PAY_PRIMARY',
        'clientDetails' => [
            'applicationId' => 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
            'ipAddress' => '127.0.0.1'
        ],
        'currencyCode' => 'USD',
        'feesPayer' => 'EACHRECEIVER',
        'memo' => 'Example',
        'receiverList' => [
            'receiver' => [
                [
                    'email' => 'A-Primary@appinventiv.com',
                    'primary' => true,
                    'amount' => 25,
                ],
                [
                    'email' => 'B-Second@appinventiv.com',
                    'primary' => false,
                    'amount' => 20,
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'requestEnvelope' => [
            'errorLanguage' => 'en_US'
        ],
        'returnUrl' => 'http://localhost/hairInferno/success.php',
        'cancelUrl' => 'http://localhost/hairInferno/success.php'
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive Payments was discontinued in December 2017 and no new APP IDs are generated for use in the live environment, so I'd drop this integration pattern

You could look around the PayPal for Partners documentation, but I'm not sure whether any of this would be available to you: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/partners/

Something with Payouts might be the best interim solution: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/